# Wordpress Menu Breakpoints with Bootstrap navwalker

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I have looked at previous questions related to this and they just are not working out for me. My menu works fine; I just want to make the breakpoints for the mobile menu a lot larger so it will be the drop down on iPad's held portrait instead of just phones.

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve this? It should be fairly simple to edit the CSS parts for this

Comment: ive looked in inspect element tried to find some sort of @media to copy and paste in my custom css with a larger breakpoint but i feel like its more javascript based as it did not work. i was hoping to find someone who has used this navalker in the past in a wordpress theme